# Change md-tab-group body min height to 0 in Angular 2 Material

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, material-design, angular2-material

Here is [a plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nle5Y8HfmWLu7IPsxI4p?p=preview) that uses Angular 2 Material `md-tab-group` component.

Basically, this

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>Tab</template>
        <template md-tab-content>
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <p>200 px height</p>
            </md-content>
        </template>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

renders to a tab that has a body with 200px height. It uses flex layout, and I cannot find from the sources how to change minimum height. Actually, this style is listed for `md-tab-group`:

```
[_nghost-vvf-2] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    min-height: 248px;
}
```

How can minimum height be restored to 0 for `md-tab-group` properly? And where did this `min-height` come from?

---

It appears that the problem is specific to `2.0.0-alpha.5` and `2.0.0-alpha.5-2`, it doesn't appear in `master`.

Comment: Take a look at this line https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.5/src/components/tabs/tab-group.scss#L11 Notice tag `alpha.5`

Comment: @yurzui Most obvious and reasonable explanation, thank you! I'm taking a good note of `master`s. Usually I clone them to examine code, and they failed me at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have noticed, 48px height is declared for childs of 'md-tab-label'

   .md-tab-label[_ngcontent-rru-2] {
   line-height: 48px;
   height: 48px;}
2. So remaining height(200px) is taken by the  'md-tab-content'.
3. You can override the min-height to zero for 'md-tab-group' in your app CSS file. (read CSS specificity)

Answer (score 1):

min-height can be restored in component style attribute;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles: [`
md-tab-group {
  background:#fff;
  min-height:0;
}
  `],
  directives: [MD_TABS_DIRECTIVES]
})
```